# Pdf contents using CGPDFDocumentGetCatalog and CGPDFPage is getting complex

Tags: objective-c, swift, file, pdf

I want to get the types of the content in the PDF file. Then read the content and convert all text contents to string. So far I know I can get the type of the content using *CGPDFDocumentGetCatalog*. I also know that *CGPDFDocumentGetCatalog* returns a *CGPDFDictionaryRef*. What I don't know is how to access the content of the dictionary, due to the fact, that I don't know the keys name. Here is my code:

```
    var myDoc: CGPDFDocument!

    myDoc = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(url)
    if pdfDoc != nil {
    let pdfCatalog=CGPDFDocumentGetCatalog(myDoc)

    //here I want to get the types of the content. something like pdfCatalog["type"]         
    }
```

Since I was not able to get the type of the contents I decided to go for a simple pdf with only text.

I am able to get the pages using *CGPDFDocumentGetPage*. However I am not able to get the content of the page convertible to string. So far this is what I have got.

```
  let numOfPages = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages (myDoc)
        for (k = 0; k < numOfPages; k!++) {
           var myPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage (myDoc, k! + 1 );
            var myContentStream = CGPDFContentStreamCreateWithPage (myPage);

        }
```

Obviously this is getting the PDF document, but I can't really access it. *CGPDFDocumentGetPage* returns *CGPDFPage* and I am not able to access its content. *CGPDFContentStreamCreateWithPage* function returns *CGPDFContentStreamRef*, from which I can't retrieve the content.

Please how do I go about it. what do I need to read about.

Comment: What you are trying to do is very difficult. You may be able to find some libraries that can help. Search for something like "library to extract text from PDFs". If you want to understand the structure of PDF documents, look at the PDF Specification. But be warned: it is long and complex.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. What is surprising to me is that I was expecting, that getting information from catalogs to be easy